# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addIceCandidate' of undefined

Tags: javascript, c#, signalr, webrtc

well I will jump into code part since the header is the problem im facing and I couldnt find any better ways to describe it

```
function addIceCandidate(message) {
    if (message.candidate != null) {
        console.trace('add ice candidate');
        var iceCandidate = new RTCIceCandidate(message.candidate);
        pc1.addIceCandidate(iceCandidate);
    }    
}
```

is the function who tries to send ice candidate to the remote peer but in remote peer's chrome debugger it says

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addIceCandidate' of undefined
>   and

```
pc1.addIceCandidate(iceCandidate);
```

is the line where the error happens

But to my knowladge `addIceCandidate` is a WebRTC function which is already defined.

so what am I doing wrong?

I have already gone through [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCPeerConnection/addIceCandidate) , and for similar problems [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37266419/webrtc-error-undefined-configuration), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46071783/cannot-read-property-createdatachannel-of-undefined) and also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44474775/webrtc-onremote-stream-null)

and also for the full project Gist is [here](https://gist.github.com/Kriegthor23/54c1a246cba6e9fb9096c161edc99a59)

Ty for helps in advance and please inform me if you need additional infomation

Comment: check `pc1`, I think it is undefined

Comment: Here issue is not with addIceCandidate but with object pc1, it says pc1 is undefined. check pc1 first.

Comment: @RaviMariya actually it is defined in call() method but i moved it up to top but does not change the situation

Comment: i got your problem, your pc1 is undefined in remote pc, you need to make sure you have pc1  before calling addIceCandidate in remote pc

Comment: @RaviMariya pc1 is not undefined it was defined at method call()  but then i moved it on to the top 

var pc1;
var servers = { 'iceServers': [{ 'urls': 'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302' }] };
pc1 = new RTCPeerConnection(servers);

here is the definition for you this is not still working

Comment: write `console.log(pc1)`  before `pc1.addIceCandidate(iceCandidate);` and see what it prints

Comment: @RaviMariya http://tinypic.com/r/2wg99jq/9 you can look at the console log for it from the link

Comment: @HaydarKutayÖzcan I added answer. hope it will help you in understanding the code and work as per your expectation. Thanks.

Comment: @RohitJindal thank you for your help and work but had some questions and asked them in comment . im building up a WebTC application so your answer was quite interesting for me.

Comment: See https://www.w3.org/TR/webrtc/#call-flow-browser-to-browser

Answer (score 0):

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addIceCandidate' of undefined

This line itself having answer of your question. `pc1` object is not defined on which you are trying to access `addIceCandidate` property.

**Working code :**

```js
var pc1 = {
  addIceCandidate : function(val) {
    console.log(val);
  }
}

function addIceCandidate(message) {
    if (message.candidate != null) {
        pc1.addIceCandidate(message.candidate);
    }    
}

var data = {
  "candidate": "Rohit"
}

addIceCandidate(data);
```

Comment: may i ask you something? is this code working in the context of WebRTC? if so can you show your search results about it for me to learn more? because pc1 = new RTCPeerConnection(servers);  is my definition on my current code and even on MDN  it says addIceCandidate is defined in WebRTC so can you give some more details please?

Comment: @HaydarKutayÖzcan I dont have an idea of WebRTC. So i can not help you in that.

Answer (score 0):

Things to remember:

1. Once the connection, `pc1`, receives an ice candidate via `onicecandidate()` event handler, `pc1` should send the ice candidate to the remote peer via the signaling server.
2. Remote peer should use [`RTCPeerConnection`](https://www.w3.org/TR/webrtc/#dom-rtcpeerconnection)'s [`addIceCandidate()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/webrtc/#dom-rtcpeerconnection-addicecandidate) to add the ice candidate received via the signaling server.

See [Simple Peer-to-Peer Example](https://www.w3.org/TR/webrtc/#simple-peer-to-peer-example)